# Validar mensagem lida ou não lida

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um sistema de email. Agora pretendo verificar as mensagens lidas (aparecem sem bold) e não lidas (aparecem a bold) pelo utilizador. 
Crio a tabela com os emails desta forma:

```
<?php  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {  
?> 
<section id="s1">
<div class="div1" id="minhaDiv" style="float: left;">  
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr> 
            <th width="20%">De</th>
            <th width="60%">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%">Recebido</th>               
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: <?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></th>

        </tr>       

        <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td>
        <td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" <?php echo $row["Status"] != '1'?' Normal ':' negrito '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php  
        }  
        ?> 
    </table>  
</div>
</section>
```

Para ler o conteúdo da mensagem clico nesta td e abre um modal:

```
<td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>
```

Ao abrir o modal com o click faço update na coluna Status da tabela da base de dados de 1 para 0, para ficar como lida e na td acima faço essa verificação da seguinte forma:

```
width="20%" <?php echo $row["Status"] == '1'?' style="font-weight:bold" ':' style="font-weight:normal" '?>
```

o JavaScript para abrir o modal e fazer o update:

```
$('.td-info').click(function(){
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var status = $(this).attr("Status");
      $.ajax({ 
        url:"./fetchRAD",  
        method: "POST",  
        data:{item_id:item_id, status:status},   
        success:function(data){     
                }
      });               
    });
```

Mas o problema, é que ao mudar o valor do Status para 0, se for um utilizador diferente também já vai mostrar como lida a mensagem. Então pretendia fazer esta verificação do lado do cliente e não do lado da base de dados.

Tabela para registar mensagens:

```
CREATE TABLE `Alertas` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Tipo` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prioridade` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Para` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Assunto` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Conteudo` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Recebido` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `De` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Utilizadores que podem receber em grupo ou individualmente:

```
CREATE TABLE `testeCol` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Colaborador` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grupo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela para preencher o status como lida:

```
CREATE TABLE `ValAlertas` (
  `IdVal` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IdSMS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Para` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdVal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você crie na tabela do banco a coluna que diz o status da mensagem(Lida ou Não-lida). E na tela de exibição das mensagens utiliza um filtro e verifique se no banco diz se a mensagem foi lida, exemplo:

```
<?php if($row['status'] == 'lida'): ?>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold">  
        <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td>
        <td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" <?php echo $row["Status"] != '1'?' Normal ':' negrito '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php else: ?>
    <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td>
        <td class="td-info view_data" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#dataModal" width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" <?php echo $row["Status"] != '1'?' Normal ':' negrito '?>><?php echo $row["Assunto"]; ?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sim, dessa forma eu já tinha feito, o problema é que existem vários usuários, o primeiro ao ler troca o campo de status para lida e depois todos vão receber a mensagem como lida, e na verdade só o primeiro usuário leu

Comment: Pera aí? a mensagem é compartilhada?

Comment: Sim, a mensagem é para vários utilizadores, podem haver situações em que não depende dos utilizadores que selecionam o envio. O ideal era validar do lado do cliente e não em base de dados

Comment: No entanto no Client-side não tem como "Salvar" o ideal é que vc salve no banco com uma tabela. exemplo: tabela "leitura-usuário" que teria 4 campos: id, user_id, mensagem_id, status.
Caso o usuário 2 leia a mensagem 15 vc salva id=x; user_id=2; mensagem_id=15; status="lida".

Comment: Sim essa forma é a que estou a fazer, mas surge outro problema. A mensagem pode ser enviada para usuários específicos ou então para um grupo. Esse grupo refere-se por exemplo a 4 usuários, nesta situação vou ter o mesmo problema. Pergunto, eu ao selecionar o grupo, depois quando faço o insert é possível inserir uma linha para casa usuário que pertence aquele grupo?

Comment: Seria interessante se você editasse a pergunta e explicasse mais sobre seu projeto, bem como a estrutura do seu banco.

Comment: editei a pergunta com a informação completa

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91665/discussion-between-bruno-and-vinicius-de-jesus).

Answer (score 0):

Isso resolve:

```
<th width="20%" style="font-weight:bold" onclick="this.style['font-weight'] ='normal'">De</th>
```

Comment: é isso que pretendo, mas só existe um problema, sempre que atualizo a página volta a ficar negrito e não devia, depois de clicar uma vez, mesmo que atualize a página já não devia aparecer a negrito

Comment: Sugiro então que você salve a condição da Td no banco. no entanto cada td deveria ter um id.